# Allow Access To Subfolder Of HTML For Logged In Visitors

Tags: html, directory, user-access

I have a WordPress site installed in the root folder. Beneath the root is a /docs folder with a bunch of older html files. I'd like to allow only logged in WordPress users to be able to have access to those /docs html pages (not to be confused with WordPress 'pages').

I created a WordPress 'portal' page which displays links to the /docs pages if the visitor is logged in. I would also like to put in a textual search function (which I know how to do) so logged in visitors can get a list of relevant /docs html pages

What I *don't* know how to do is prevent *not* logged in visitors from direct access to the /docs pages for both links and searches?

I know I could do these if I converted the html pages to php and checked a referer. But I don't want to have to redo all the old html if possible (if I have to do *that* I'll just import them into a WordPress taxonomy -- but I hope to avoid that!)

I looked at .htaccess and I was hoping to perhaps set an ENV variable or use REFERER, but I keep reading that such things are not reliable.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/password-protect-a-whole-directory) - it covers using .htaccess to protect a directory based on a WordPress logged in cookie.

The .htaccess in case the thread goes missing - obviously you'll need to change `uploads/premium` to your directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/premium/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Edit**: toscho has rightly pointed out this method is unreliable, as cookies are browser-based and easily spoofed.  So, I'd like to add one more method: [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html).  Quick and dirty, and probably horribly thought out, definitely a better way somewhere, but overall worth a shot.  Basically, you'll do a global find/replace then a global rename on the html files in your `/docs` directory.  Assuming your files all begin with `<!DOCTYPE`, simply find `<!DOCTYPE` and replace with this:

```
<?php include_once('/wp-config.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{ print <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE
```

Then find your closing `</html>` tag and replace it with this:

```
</html>
HTML;
} else {
echo 'Who are you and how did you get this number?';
?>
```

Batch change the filenames to `.php` using [Renamer](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/denrenamer.html) or something similar, and viola - you've added WordPress functionality to your static html files.  Of course, make sure you have a backup of your files before doing any bulk operations, no matter how certain you are they'll work.  All it takes is one little typo and you've set yourself up for hours of tedious work reverting it.

Comment: Everybody can send such a cookie. ;)

Comment: Of course they can, hence it not being reliable.  But, it's better than nothing, and can work as a stopgap in the meantime.  With the requirement of 'test against user logged in', the only other options are 'try out plugins for role management and hope for the best' or 'global find/replace to wrap the HTML in heredoc syntax and rename all to .php'.  Neither of those are as quick-and-dirty as this, though - although the heredoc (while ugly) is probably the next quickest.

Comment: Hi, O/P here. The problem is that all the static html pages have lots and lots of <a hrefs> to various pages within the folder. So if I rename to php, then I have to go through every file and redo the links. I have tried doing regex changes before and something -always- goes wrong. Any suggestions on how to handle the links? --JC

Comment: Sure - do a global find/replace for `.html"` to `.php"`.  The closing quote means it should only be replacing them inside the `<a href="something.html">`, without messing up any other tags.  No need to write a regex, just Notepad++'s "find in files" function.  Again, back up your folder to a safe place before starting, just in case.